# Vuex store - callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Why do I keep getting the error "callback is not a function" in this action in my Vuex store?

```
updateRemoteUser: ({ state, commit }, callback) => {
  const user = state.user
  axios.put(`/users/${user.id}`, { 
    user: user
  })
    .then(response => {
      commit('changeUser', response.data.user)
      callback(true)
    })
    .catch(errors => {
      console.log(errors)
      callback(false)
    })
},
```

EDIT
And then I'm calling the above action like this:

```
async setResponses() {
  this.userResponse = await this.updateRemoteUser()
  if(this.userResponse) {
    this.$router.push({ name: 'weddingDetails' })
  }
  else {
    console.log("Something is jacked")
  }
},
```

Comment: Can you show us the line of code where you actually call the action updateRemoteUser?

Comment: @JohnSmith Just updated the question with how I'm using those callbacks..

Answer (score 0):

Check if callback is actually being passed to tee action. A simple check would reveal the answer

```
if (!callback) console.log('tada');
```

Comment: This would not reveal the answer in case the callback variable is any primitive type or object. It would be better to check whether the callback is typeof 'function'.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the mutation...

```
this.updateRemoteUser({ 
    callback: (e) => console.log('do something') 
})
```

On Your Vuex

```
updateRemoteUser: ({ state, commit }, data) => {
   const user = state.user
   axios.put(`/users/${user.id}`, { 
    user: user
  })
 .then(response => {
    commit('changeUser', response.data.user)
     if (data.callback) data.callback(true)
  })
  .catch(errors => {
    console.log(errors)
    if (data.callback) data.callback(false)
  })
},
```